# CMFCToolbar layout not restored properly between sessions

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc-feature-pack

I'm having a problem with the CMFCToolbar class where the positions of the toolbars are not being restored properly between sessions.

Here is a screen shot of how the toolbars are arranged before the app is closed:

[image]
<sub>(source: [achavis.net](http://www.achavis.net/toolbar1.png))</sub>

Here is a screen shot of how the toolbars are restored when the app is launched again:

[image]
<sub>(source: [achavis.net](http://www.achavis.net/toolbar2.png))</sub>

Notice the large gap that appears above the first toolbar and the second toolbar is now to the right of the main toolbar instead of beneath it.

I was having problems with my app, so I generated this test app using the App Wizard, then I added the second toolbar manually.

I would like to know if this is because there is something I am doing wrong, or if it is just due to the buggy nature of the feature pack code.

Here is the code from my CMainFrame class which sets up the toolbars:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CFrameWndEx::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    BOOL bNameValid;

    // set the visual manager used to draw all user interface elements
    CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007));

    // set the visual style to be used the by the visual manager
    CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::SetStyle(CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::Office2007_LunaBlue);

    if (!m_wndMenuBar.Create(this))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create menubar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    m_wndMenuBar.SetPaneStyle(m_wndMenuBar.GetPaneStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY);

    // prevent the menu bar from taking the focus on activation
    CMFCPopupMenu::SetForceMenuFocus(FALSE);

    if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
        !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDR_MAINFRAME_256 : IDR_MAINFRAME))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    CString strToolBarName;
    bNameValid = strToolBarName.LoadString(IDS_TOOLBAR_STANDARD);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    m_wndToolBar.SetWindowText(strToolBarName);

    m_wndToolBar.EnableTextLabels();

    if (!m_wndToolBar2.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
        !m_wndToolBar2.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar2\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }

    CString strCustomize("Toolbar2");
    m_wndToolBar2.EnableCustomizeButton(TRUE, ID_VIEW_CUSTOMIZE, strCustomize);

    // Allow user-defined toolbars operations:
    InitUserToolbars(NULL, uiFirstUserToolBarId, uiLastUserToolBarId);

    if (!m_wndStatusBar.Create(this))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create status bar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }
    m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators, sizeof(indicators)/sizeof(UINT));

    // TODO: Delete these five lines if you don't want the toolbar and menubar to be dockable
    m_wndMenuBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    m_wndToolBar2.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockPane(&m_wndMenuBar);
    DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);
    DockPane(&m_wndToolBar2);


    // enable Visual Studio 2005 style docking window behavior
    CDockingManager::SetDockingMode(DT_SMART);
    // enable Visual Studio 2005 style docking window auto-hide behavior
    EnableAutoHidePanes(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);

    // Load menu item image (not placed on any standard toolbars):
    CMFCToolBar::AddToolBarForImageCollection(IDR_MENU_IMAGES, theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDB_MENU_IMAGES_24 : 0);

    // create docking windows
    if (!CreateDockingWindows())
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create docking windows\n");
        return -1;
    }

    m_wndFileView.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    m_wndClassView.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockPane(&m_wndFileView);
    CDockablePane* pTabbedBar = NULL;
    m_wndClassView.AttachToTabWnd(&m_wndFileView, DM_SHOW, TRUE, &pTabbedBar);
    m_wndOutput.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockPane(&m_wndOutput);


    // Enable toolbar and docking window menu replacement
    EnablePaneMenu(TRUE, ID_VIEW_CUSTOMIZE, strCustomize, ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR);

    // enable quick (Alt+drag) toolbar customization
    CMFCToolBar::EnableQuickCustomization();

    if (CMFCToolBar::GetUserImages() == NULL)
    {
        // load user-defined toolbar images
        if (m_UserImages.Load(_T(".\\UserImages.bmp")))
        {
            m_UserImages.SetImageSize(CSize(16, 16), FALSE);
            CMFCToolBar::SetUserImages(&m_UserImages);
        }
    }

    // enable menu personalization (most-recently used commands)
    // TODO: define your own basic commands, ensuring that each pulldown menu has at least one basic command.
    CList<UINT, UINT> lstBasicCommands;

    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_NEW);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_OPEN);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_SAVE);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_FILE_PRINT);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_APP_EXIT);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_EDIT_CUT);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_EDIT_PASTE);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_EDIT_UNDO);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_APP_ABOUT);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_VIEW_STATUS_BAR);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_SORTING_SORTALPHABETIC);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_SORTING_SORTBYTYPE);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_SORTING_SORTBYACCESS);
    lstBasicCommands.AddTail(ID_SORTING_GROUPBYTYPE);

    CMFCToolBar::SetBasicCommands(lstBasicCommands);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was resolved by creating the toolbars **with explicit IDs** as opposed to relying on the default parameter as in the above code.

Because the registry key that the toolbar's state is saved to is based on the ID, the second toolbar was saving its state on top of the first toolbar.

Here are the code changes that resolved the problem:

```
if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC, CRect(1,1,1,1), IDR_MAINFRAME) ||
    !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDR_MAINFRAME_256 : IDR_MAINFRAME))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
```

...

```
if (!m_wndToolBar2.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC, CRect(1,1,1,1), IDR_TOOLBAR) ||
    !m_wndToolBar2.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar2\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}
```